# Objective : To execute a function in on route change but useEffect with dependency array = [location] or [location.pathname] not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Below is the code for doing the same. handleRouteChange() does not execute on route change for some reason.

```
   // checking if location is home
   const [isHome, setIsHome] = useState(false);
   const handleRouteChange = () => {
       if (location.pathname === '/') setIsHome(true);
       else setIsHome(false);
       console.log(location.pathname);
   };
   useEffect(() => {
       handleRouteChange();
   }, [location.pathname]);
```

This code is inside the navbar component. Below is the routing setup inside the App component.

```
function App() {
    const RouteList = ROUTES.map((route) => (
        <Route path={route.path} Component={route.element} key={route.path} />
    ));

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Navbar />
            <Routes>{RouteList}</Routes>
            <Footer />
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

dependency versions

"react-router-dom": "^6.14.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",

link : [codesandbox replication](https://codesandbox.io/s/route-change-check-vhnjcn)

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox? That would be really helpful for you and to the people answering

Comment: Did. Also I found that the function is executed when the url is manually changed but does not execute when it is changed by clicking on the <Link> tags in the navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `window.location`. You need to use react-router-dom `useLocation()` hook.

Try it out

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  // checking if location is home
  const [isHome, setIsHome] = useState(false);

  //react-router-dom hook
  let location = useLocation();

  const handleRouteChange = () => {
    if (location.pathname === "/") setIsHome(true);
    else setIsHome(false);
    console.log(location.pathname);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("location changed!")
    handleRouteChange();
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
      <br />
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```